# Golang merge deeply two maps

Tags: dictionary, go, merge, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deep copy of two yaml, trying to simulate the behaviour that use [helm](https://github.com/helm/) when you pass multiple values during an installation.
Because of a project restriction, I'm getting the values from strings and not directly form yamls.
The problem is that the copy is not done as I expect.

I add an example:

**value1**:

```
test:
  somekey: 1
  otherkey: 2
othertest:
  somekey: 3
```

**value2**:

```
test:
  somekey: NEWVALUE1
  NEWKEY: NEWVALUE2
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**:

```
test:
  somekey: NEWVALUE1
  otherkey: 2
  NEWKEY: NEWVALUE2
othertest:
  somekey: 3
```

**RESULT**:

```
othertest:
  somekey: 3
test:
  NEWKEY: NEWVALUE2
  somekey: NEWVALUE1
```

So as you can see in the example, it is overwritting all the `test` map, when I would like to merge both `test` maps.

Here I add the code I'm using

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/prometheus/common/log"
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"
)

func main() {
    value1 := "test:\n  somekey: 1\n  otherkey: 2\nothertest:\n  somekey: 3"
    value2 := "test:\n  somekey: NEWVALUE1\n  NEWKEY: NEWVALUE2"
    values := []string{value1, value2}
    result, err := getValuesFromString(values)
    if err != nil {
        log.Info(err)
    }

    //expecting: test:\n  somekey: NEWVALUE1\n  otherkey: 2\n  NEWKEY: NEWVALUE2\nothertest:\n  somekey: 3
    //getting: othertest:\n  somekey: 3\ntest:\n  NEWKEY: NEWVALUE2\n  somekey: NEWVALUE1\n
    log.Info("FINAL VALUES: " + result)
}

func getValuesFromString(values []string) (string, error) {

    var resultValues map[string]interface{}
    var bs []byte
    for _, value := range values {
        log.Info(values)
        var override map[string]interface{}
        bs = []byte(value)

        if err := yaml.Unmarshal(bs, &override); err != nil {
            log.Info(err)
            continue
        }

        //check if is nil. This will only happen for the first value
        if resultValues == nil {
            resultValues = override
        } else {
            resultValues = mergeMaps(resultValues, override)
        }
    }

    bs, err := yaml.Marshal(resultValues)
    if err != nil {
        log.Info(err)
        return "", err
    }

    return string(bs), nil
}

func mergeMaps(a, b map[string]interface{}) map[string]interface{} {
    out := make(map[string]interface{}, len(a))
    for k, v := range a {
        out[k] = v
    }
    for k, v := range b {
        if v, ok := v.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
            if bv, ok := out[k]; ok {
                if bv, ok := bv.(map[string]interface{}); ok {
                    out[k] = mergeMaps(bv, v)
                    continue
                }
            }
        }
        out[k] = v
    }
    return out
}
```

I think the error is that I'm generating incorrectly the map from the string `var resultValues map[string]interface{}`, but I didn't find the way to convert the string to a map

Comment: Is `NEWVALUE2x` a mistake?

Comment: Yes. edited. `NEWKEY: NEWVALUE2`

Comment: I found lots of questions in [tag:go] which was clear enough and also showed some efforts always get downvote.:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map[interface{}]interface{}` instead of `map[string]interface{}`. You could have a deeper look at [yaml.Unmarshal](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2?tab=doc#Unmarshal).

```golang
func mergeMaps(a, b map[interface{}]interface{}) map[interface{}]interface{} {
    out := make(map[interface{}]interface{}, len(a))
    for k, v := range a {
        out[k] = v
    }
    for k, v := range b {
        // If you use map[string]interface{}, ok is always false here.
        // Because yaml.Unmarshal will give you map[interface{}]interface{}.
        if v, ok := v.(map[interface{}]interface{}); ok {
            if bv, ok := out[k]; ok {
                if bv, ok := bv.(map[interface{}]interface{}); ok {
                    out[k] = mergeMaps(bv, v)
                    continue
                }
            }
        }
        out[k] = v
    }
    return out
}
```

Comment: Could I consider `interface{}` as the `Generic` in GO?

Comment: It is more similar to `void*`, it is not even close to generics/templates